# Switching between 2 Löve2D versions

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, versions

Perhaps I should ask this question in the Game Development QA. But I am using the Löve2D Engine on Ubuntu 14.04, and this is technically an OS management situation, so here it goes:

#### Situation

The current version (the one I installed) is *0.9.1*, but some projects will only run with version *0.8.**. I know I can install different versions of the engine.

#### Question

How do I install another version alongside the current one?

And how do I switch between versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Love uses same package name for different major versions. I don't know what's the point from using `update-alternatives` if two version can not be installed directly through package manager. I think this should be reported as a bug.

As you have v0.9.1. Let's add v0.8.0 available in Ubuntu repository.

1. Download it

   ```
   sudo apt-get download love
   ```
2. Extract it

   ```
   dpkg-deb -x love_*.deb tmp/
   ```
3. Copy to `bin/` folder and install it as alternative

   ```
   bin_name=`ls tmp/usr/bin/`
   sudo cp tmp/usr/bin/$bin_name /usr/bin/
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/love love /usr/bin/$bin_name 5
   ```

To switch:

- either using `love-0.8` or `love-0.9` explicitly
- or change using:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config love
  ```

  May be easier if you create an `alias`. then `love` will point to the to chosen version

To check current setting:

```
update-alternatives --query love
```

Comment: Your answer was not only insightful, but nicely laid out. Thanks.